# Update+Inner Join - ERR.1442: Can't update table in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function

Tags: sql, mysql, join, mysql-error-1442

I'm struggling a little with this query:

```
update parti p
inner join parmag c on p.Prec_parti=c.Precodice AND p.Cod_parti=c.Parte
SET p.Cat_sconto="RC10"
WHERE p.Prec_parti="XXX" AND p.Cod_parti="YYYY" AND c.Costo_Ultimo < 10;
```

When I launch it, I get the topic error:

> ERR.1442: Can't update table in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function

Any hint or workaround to launch the query?